# How to get rid of added URLs when printing a Bootstrap-themed page?

Tags: javascript

When I print a page from my Bootstrap-themed site, all the links (and images with attached urls) have a printed representation of the link inserted into the printed page, right after the linked object.  I can see some situations where this would be helpful, but for now it's just messing up my printed layout.  I smell jQuery at work here, but I can't figure out where it is or how I can turn it off.  Any hints out there?  Thanks!

Comment: FWIW: is Bootstrap related; not specific to Drupal nor jquery.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Found it: it wasn't jQuery, but CSS3.  Down in bootstrap.css, we find:

```
@media print {
  ...
  a[href]:after {
    content: " (" attr(href) ")";
  }
  ...
}
```

Overriding the style with `content:none` handles the situation fine.  There are some similar `:after` clauses in there doing similar things, but this is working for now.

Comment: FYI, I first read this as hand-modifying bootstrap.css, which I was reluctant to do. Of course it isn't saying that: "overriding the style" just means putting a new definition in one's own style sheet, that is loaded after the bootstrap one. Probably obvious to most people, but I mention this in case anyone else has the same mis-interpretation I did.

Comment: This odd design choice has been "[fixed](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/17788)" in bootstrap 4.